# implying the file name in php

Tags: php

hello everybody
i have been asked to design a general login page (and others) for a website. what i need is when any user simply clicks on the website's name; the user is directly taken to the login page. the site is designed so that one cannot enter without being logged in. any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: This is a very broad question. What kind of login system are you planning to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking for here. From a quick read of the OP question, it appears you are wanting to direct people to the login page if they visit the main page and are not logged in.

To do this, all you need do is, in the main page, test whether the user is logged in. If they are not, then you redirect them to the login page.

```
<?php
// Within the INDEX.PHP file, at the very top
// - nothing can be infront of the opening tag for this PHP section.
session_start();
if( $_SESSION['loggedIn']!=true ){
  header( 'Location: login.php' );
  die();
}
```

This will redirect anyone viewing *index.php* to the *login.php* page, if they are not logged in. So long as, when they are logged in, you set `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` to `true` (otherwise everyone, everytime, will be sent to the login page).

Comment: Thanx Lucanos. Bt that was not what I was looking for. My login page is entitled login.php. All i want is whenever a user types the websites name in the url, the user is redirected to login.php. Hope I'm clearer this time. Thanx in advance

Comment: That is not really any clearer. You want someone tying your URL "http://www.server.com" into a browser window to be redirected to the Login Page "login.php". My code above will do precisely that.

Comment: (Note: "...whenever a user types the websites name in the url..." is especially inclear. A website's name may be "Stack Overflow", the URL is "http://stackoverflow.com/". They are two separate things, which, although related, are not identical.)

Comment: Thanks Lucanos. I guess i was confused myself and was confusin further. I have got it now. Thanks again.